# Sort array based on min and max date?

Tags: javascript, sorting, datetime, underscore.js

Basically I have an array of dates:

```
var array = ["2017-01-22 00:21:17.0",
           "2017-01-27 11:30:23.0",
           "2017-01-24 15:53:21.0",
           "2017-01-27 11:34:18.0",
           "2017-01-26 16:55:48.0",
           "2017-01-22 11:57:12.0",
           "2017-01-27 11:35:43.0"];
```

Which I need to sort this based on max and min date;
I tried:

```
var lowest = _.max(array, function(o){return o.val;});
console.log(lowest);
```

But this returns `-Infinity` and _.min returns `Infinity`

Regards :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Comment: Simply get rid of the `function` part: `_.min(array), _.max(array)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) without callback. This sorts by string, which gets the min value at index zero and at the last index the max date.

```js
var array = ["2017-01-22 00:21:17.0", "2017-01-27 11:30:23.0", "2017-01-24 15:53:21.0", "2017-01-27 11:34:18.0", "2017-01-26 16:55:48.0", "2017-01-22 11:57:12.0", "2017-01-27 11:35:43.0"];

array.sort();
console.log(array);
console.log('min', array[0]);
console.log('max', array[array.length - 1]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another solution could be the use of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var array = ["2017-01-22 00:21:17.0", "2017-01-27 11:30:23.0", "2017-01-24 15:53:21.0", "2017-01-27 11:34:18.0", "2017-01-26 16:55:48.0", "2017-01-22 11:57:12.0", "2017-01-27 11:35:43.0"],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        if (!i) {
            return { min: a, max: a};
        }
        if (a < r.min) {
            r.min = a;
        }
        if (a > r.max) {
            r.max = a;
        }
        return r;
    }, undefined);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: So I suppose in order to get the max value, I need to read array in reverse  order? Okay I didn't thought it might be this easy.

Comment: be very careful using the first method. The default sort order is according to string Unicode points and has nothing to do with comparing dates. There are probably edge cases where it falls apart (especially if you have any formatted differently), but it will work on the array you provided.

Comment: @damon Thanks, That is the only sort of array I'm gonna have for sorting.

Comment: @Damon, ISO date strings are sortable as strings, there are no edge cases.

Comment: @NinaScholz good to know, I figured if the formatting is valid it will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = ["2017-01-22 00:21:17.0",
           "2017-01-27 11:30:23.0",
           "2017-01-24 15:53:21.0",
           "2017-01-27 11:34:18.0",
           "2017-01-26 16:55:48.0",
           "2017-01-22 11:57:12.0",
           "2017-01-27 11:35:43.0"];

var timeStamped = array.map((item) => new Date(item).getTime());

console.log('Max is ', new Date(Math.max.apply(null,timeStamped)). toUTCString());

console.log('Min is ', new Date(Math.min.apply(null,timeStamped)). toUTCString());
```